# preg, преобразование строки в полиндром

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Требуется, применив строку-иголку `needle` `'аргентинаманитнегра'` к строке-стогу `haystack` `' Аргентина пр ро Аргентина манит негра бдщ негра '`, получить на выходе результат - `'Аргентина манит негра'`.

Как элегантнее всего осуществить задуманное, и возможно ли это сделать в один приём через регулярное выражение?

Для обработки полиндрома, вернее наибольшего под-полиндрома, я не представляю как обойтись без приведения строки к нижнему регистру и удалению пробелов, но хотелось бы, да в общем так и нужно по заданию, привести его именно в такой 
вид.

В регулярных выражениях не сильно силён, вот подумал может это возможно сделать более элегантно, чем сейчас пытаюсь сделать я, вычисляя кучу подстрок, их длины, подстроки с пробелами с разных позиций, их длины и вырезание по-средством `mb_substr` результирующей строки из позиции и длин ранее определённых строк? :-)

```
' Аргентина пр ро Аргентина манит негра бдщ негра '
'аргентинаманитнегра'
'Аргентина манит негра'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось так:

```
<?php

$pattern = 'аргентинаманитнегра';
$text = ' Аргентина пр ро Аргентина манит негра бдщ негра ';

// разбить в массив на символы unicode
preg_match_all('/./u', $pattern, $re);

// в начале и конце re - критерий границы слова \b
// между буквами - произвольное количество пробельных символов \s*
$re = '/\b'.implode("\s*", $re[0]).'\b/ui';

// сопоставление
preg_match($re, $text, $m);

// результат
echo $m[0];
```

Comment: Благодарю. это именно то, что мне тогда было нужно. :)

Answer (score 0):

Получилось нечто страшное... :-(
Хотя и работает как нужно, но меня не покидает чувство, что эту функцию можно переписать красиво и элегантно на регулярках.

```
function format($hst, $ndl)
{
    if (!isset($hst, $ndl) || !$hst || !$ndl) return false;
    $arr = preg_split('//u', $hst, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    for($i=0,$l=mb_strlen($ndl); isset($arr[$i]); ++$i)
        if (($s1 = trim(mb_substr($str, $i))) && mb_substr(mb_strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $s1)), 0, $l) == $ndl)
            for($i=0; isset($s1[$i]); ++$i)
                if (($s2 = trim(mb_substr($s1, 0, ($i?-$i:null)))) && mb_strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $s2)) == $ndl)
                    return $s2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну если просто подогнать под условие :

```
$needle = 'аргентинаманитнегра';
$haystack = ' Аргентина пр ро Аргентина манит негра бдщ негра ';

array_map(function($word)use(&$return , $needle){
        $return .= (strrpos($needle , $word) !== false ? $word.' ' : '');
} , array_unique(explode(' ' , mb_strtolower(trim($haystack)))));

echo(ucfirst($return));
```

Comment: Благодарю, за Ваш ответ, но всё, конечно, не так просто.
`ucfirst` не работает с многобайтными кодировками, да и не обязательно самый длинный под-полиндром будет начинаться с заглавной буквы.
Смысл именно полностью выделить исходный формат из строки, по образцу, приведённому в нижний регистр и из которого удалены пробелы.

Comment: исключая `ucfirst` разве это не решает задачу?

Comment: Нет!
Это всё равно, что сказать, что `mb_substr($haystack,21,17)` решение моей задачи и недоумевать, почему оно таковым не является, ведь строку форматирует правильно.